# In topology, intA ∪ A' =?

Tags: general-topology

here, A' denotes set of limit points of A

I know that A∪A' = closure of A

and

intA ∪ boundary of A = closure of A

then what about intA ∪ A' = ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(A) = A^\circ \cup A'$. We have
$$ f(]0,1[ \cup ]1,2[) = [0,2] = (]0,1[ \cup ]1,2[)^-
$$
while
$$ f(\{0,1\}) = \emptyset
$$
so in general the result varies.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** We consider topology in continuous space here.

Since for any $x\in A^o$, there is open set $x\in G\subset A$. So $G\cap (A-\{x\})\ne \varnothing$, which means that $x\in A'$. Thus
$$
A^o\subset A'\quad\text{and }\quad A^o\cup A'=A'
$$
For discrete space above also holds despite there are lot of confusions.

Comment: Not nescessarily.  For example if N, the natural numbers, is a metric space then {2}=B (2,1/2) so {2} is an open set and 2 is interior point, but not a limit point.

Comment: No, singleton can not be open set. If singleton is open, then all set are open for arbitrary union of open sets are open. The counter  example can not hold.

Comment: ...or in other words, what if $G \cap A = \{x\} $.  Then x is not a limit point.  This can happen if the metric space has isolated points an x in A is one of them.

Comment: It is $G\cap (A-\{x\})$, not $G\cap A$

Comment: What's wrong with that?  Consider a discrete metric space such as the Natural numbers, All points are singletons and all sets are open.

Comment: In this case, what is close set and limit point set? In that case, there is no limit point set. So that case should not be considered here

Comment: $G \cap A - x $ can be empty.

Comment: Generally speaking, singleton does not have interior.

Comment: what is matter if empty?

Comment: *an* open singleton doesn't mean *all* singletons are open nor that all sets are open although that is certainly not a problem.  A singleton, x, being open does mean the is an $\epsilon $ so that there are no points, y, in the metric space such that d (x,y) $< \epsilon $.  But there are metric spaces where that can be true.

Comment: If it is empty then x is not a limit point.  Consider, again, the metric space of th Natural numbers.  All sets are open, all sets are closed, all points are singletons, and no sets have limit points.  None.

Comment: No, in general, singletons are not open and do not have interiors.  But they **can**.

Comment: In general $\operatorname{int} A \not \subset A'$.

Comment: In discrete space, thing becomes totally different. If you keep normal topology, i.e arbitrary union and finite intersection of open sets are open, then singleton can not be open set. If you agree that any set (discrete space) is the arbitrary union of singletons, then any set in discrete space is open and there is no close set except empty set.

Comment: So in discrete space, what is open set and what is closed set? One thing is sure, they are completely different from continuous space and can't be defined by $d (x,y) <ϵ$

Comment: Let X = $\mathbb R - (0,1), (1,2) $.  Let A=$[-1,0] \cup \{1\}\cup\{2\} $.  Then the set of all points that are less the 1/2 from 1 is {1}.  So $1 \in \int A $.  $\int A = (-1,0]\cup \{1\} $.  $A'=[-1,0] $

Comment: What is $∫A$? Is X=$R−(0,1)\cup (1,2)$?

Comment: In discrete *all* sets are *both* open and closed.  The metric space in this question isn't specified.  If it is R then $\int A \subset A'$ but that needn't be true if the metric space isn't R.  If the metric space has a singleton, that singleton is an interior point of every set it is in, and the singleton is not the limit point of any set.

Comment: In the Natural numbers $N_{\epsilon}(x) =\{y|d (x,y)<\epsilon\}=\{x\} $ for all $x $ and all $\epsilon <1$.  Thus all singletons are open sets.

Comment: It is impossible for all sets are both open and closed because the meaning of topology will be lost, i.e. arbitrary union and finite intersection of open sets are open, arbitrary intersection and finite union of closed sets are closed. I know there are lot of confusion in discrete space topology. So this case we only consider continuous space.

Comment: In a discrete space every set is open because every set of 1 point is an open neighborhood of that point so every point in a set is an interior set.  Every set is closed because i) the compliment of every set is open and ii) there are no limit points.

Comment: Anyway X need not be discrete.  It could be non discrete and have singletons.  If $X= [0,1)\cup \{2\} $ and $A = (0,1/2) \cup 3/4 \cup 2$ then $A' = [0,1/2] $ and $\int A =(0,1/2)\cup 2$ and $\overline A=[0,1/2]\cup 3/4\cup 2$.

Comment: In a discrete space an open set and closed sets are defined *exactly* the same as there are in any other space and they are defined be d (x,y)<epsilon.  But for every point there is always an epsilon where x is the only point in the neighborhood.  The mean all singletons are open neighborhoods, that no points are limit points, and therefore all sets are open and closed.

Comment: In your example, $A^o=(0,1/2)\subset A'$. $2$ is isolation and not in $A^o$

Comment: If  every set is closed because i) the compliment of every set is open, then there is no need to have close set. "there are no limit points", then what is closure? So your definition will not compatible with normal topology. We should define topology in discrete space compatible with continuous space

Comment: A topology space contains only open set is meaningless. In that case, what is the use of topology? In normal topology, there are open sets, closed sets and other sets that are neither open, nor closed. Topology algebra like  arbitrary union and finite intersection of open sets are open actually define the open set, which set it apart from other sets.

Comment: In my example $N_{.5}(2) = \{2\}\subset A $ so 2 most certainly **IS** an interior point. It's also an isolated point. That's not a contradiction.  A topology with only open sets (which my example ISN'T) isn't meaningless; it's trivial.  But trivial or "useless" isn't wrong or meaningless.  In my opinion restricting the OP to continuous space is too restrictive an assumption for too small a result.  The rational numbers aren't continuous.  Subspaces in general are not complete nor continous.  I'm not sure that "continuous" is even an meaningful term for metric spaces.

Comment: Google "is every interior point a limit point".  Which is what your claim is.  Also if every interior point we're a limit point then $A' = \overline A $ which would make the distinctions between $A$ and $\overline A $ "meaningless" and "useless".

Comment: How can isolation point be interior point? You should study topology more then post comment.

Comment: I've told you six or seven times how an isolated point can be an interior point.  An isolated point is one in which there are no other points in the set within a distance.  An interior point is on in which all points in the space within a distance are in the set.  If there are no points in the space within a distance of a point, then that point will be an isolated and interior point for every set it is in.  This is pretty basic stuff.  I think you should really try to understand definitions and logical implications before you criticize others.

Comment: What is interior point? For interior point, it has a open set in the original set covering it. For isolation point, it has open neighborhood not in the original set. How can it be interior? Please reference any basic topology book. Also $N_{.5}(2)\ne\{2\}$. $N_{.5}(2)$ is a ball with radius of $0.5$ at center of $2$

Comment: Exactly.  The open ball with radius .5 has *exactly* one point.  2.  {2} is an open set that covers 2, thus 2 is an interior point.  The open ball with radius .5 has no other point in the set except 2 so 2 is an isolated point.  Notice: the open ball with radius .5 i) contains no point this not in A.  This means 2 is an interior point.  ii) the open ball has no points in A other than 2.  This means it is an isolated point.  The open neiborhood with radius .5 has *ONLY* one point.  This makes {2} an open set *and* it makes 2 an isolated point.  Please, PLEASE read one of your topology texts.

Comment: The open ball with radius .5 must be in $A$ in order for 2 to be interior point. But there is no point of $A$ in the neighborhood of 2. I don't understand why you are so confused on this simple question. Please reference any basic topology book. I will not waste any time further.

Comment: Think about this.  Don't argue. Think.  Consider a metric space X, an $\x in X$ an $\epsilon > 0$.  What happens if the open ball with radius $\epsilon $ centered at x, does not have any points other than $x $.  What happens?  What *is* the open ball?  It is the set {x}. Is it open?  Yes, every point in it (x is the only point in it) has an open ball around it that is a subset of it.  $\{x\} = N_{\epsilon\}(x) \subseteq N_{\epsilon}(x) = \{x\} $.  So the singleton set *is* an open ball and is an open set.

Comment: Admittedly, this will never happen with $X=\mathbb R$ with the euclidean metric.  But it will *always* happen with $X= \mathbb R $ and the discrete metric.  Or $X= \mathbb N $ with the Euclidean metric.  Or $X = [0,1]\cup {2} $ and $x=2$.  Just THINK. Don't argue.  Think.

Comment: "But there is no point of A in the neighborhood of 2"  There are no points NOT in A in the neighborhood of 2.  I don't know why you aren't seeing *that*.  If there are no points at all then every point, all zero of them, are in A.  Open Ball = {2} $\subset$ A.  So 2 is an interior point.  Google it, read it in your text, find it in other stack exchange posts.  I am right and you are wrong.

Comment: Your reasoning is still wrong. If $X=[0,1]\cup 2$,it's still continuous space. So the open set is still open ball. 2 is isolated point and not interior point because no open ball can contain it and in X

Comment: In X=[0,1] U {2}, what is $N_{.5}(2) $= {x in X| d (x,2) < .5}?  That is an open ball, yes?  If not, why not?  What points are in it?  Is it a subset of the set  {2}?  So is {2} an open set in A with Euclid metric?  Why not? What condition does it lack?  Look, just ask your professor

Comment: Let $X =[0,1] \cap \{2\} $. Let $B=(2-.5,2+.5) \cap X $ be the open ball around 2 with radius .5. Let $A=\{2\}$. Notice: $B \subseteq A $. So 2 is an interior point of {2} and {2} is an open set in X.  **Everything** satisfies **every** definition.

Comment: The definition of interior point $x$ is that there is a open set $G$ such that $x\in G\subset A$ and $G-\{x\}\ne \varnothing$. In your case, $N_{.5}(2)-\{2\}=\varnothing$. So it won't count.

Comment: While in discrete space, interior point is not defined as that because open ball is not defined.

Comment: No.  There is NO requirement that $G - \{x\} \ne \emptyset $.  The *only* requirement is that there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\{y \in X| d(x,y) < \epsilon \subseteq G $.  *That* is the complete and only requirement for x to be an interior point.  The open ball need not contain any other point than x.  *by definition*  the singleton {2} *is* an open ball centered at 2 for all radii less an equal to 1 in X = [0,1]U{2}.  There is NO requirement that an open ball have more than one point.

Comment: In the discrete space open balls *are* defined.  They are just trivial and uninteresting.  If $\epsilon \le 1$ an open ball is a singleton.  If $\epsilon >0$ then an open ball is the entire metric space.  So all sets are open and closed, there are no limit points, and all points are isolated.  Boring.  But X=[0,1]U {2} is not discrete.

Comment: I am not sure where you get the definition of interior point. I can tell there must be non empty requirement for open set containing the point. I know there are confusions now. Some books may not have that. But If not, it must be wrong. In the discrete space open balls are not defined. If some books define it, it is not right. If singleton is open, then every set is open and close, which is totally different from continuous space and makes no sense. However I know this could be open problem and no consensus is made right now. So we should stop arguing at this moment.

Comment: So Gamelin and Green, Walter Rudin, Apostol, and Marsden (those are just the one next to my computer right now) are all "wrong" and their books are "not right"?  What books do you use?  I've never read *any* book *ever* that had a non-singleton requirement.  (Non-empty, sure, the center of the ball must be in the ball.)   Yes, all sets of "universal singletons" are both open and closed and in discrete spaces all sets *are* open and closed.  So what?  It makes perfect sense.  Open and closed are not opposites and not mutual exclusive.

Comment: You keep using "continuous" but you never define it.  What does "continuous" mean and where in the OP does it imply that only "continuous" need be discussed?

Comment: Gamelin and Greene, Introduction to Topology pg 3: "Let (X,d) be any metric space. The *open ball* B(x;r) with center $x\in X$ and radius $r > 0$ is defined by $B(x;r) = \{y \in X: d(x,y) < r\}$... Let Y be a subset of X.  A point $x \in X$ is an *interior point* of Y if there exists $r > 0$ such that $B(x;r) \subset Y$".

Comment: Walter Rudin; Principals of Mathematical Analysis p. 32 Definition 2.18: a) A *neighborhood* of a point $p$ is a set $N_r(p)$ consisting of all points $q$ such that $d(p,q) < r$.  The number $r$ is called the *radius* of $N_r(p)$.  ... e) A point $p$ is an interior point of $E$ if there is a neighborhood $N$ of $p$ such that $N \subset E$."

Comment: This is an open issue. But I can tell you that such definition is wrong regardless how famous the authors are. Again if singleton is open, then every set is open and close, which make it unnecessary for open and close set. If all set are both open and closed, why do you need them? Also it makes discrete and continuous space different (continuous space means its universe is R and beyond). However, it is an open issue that the problems remain to be made clear completely. So you can have your opinion.

Comment: It's not opinion or a matter of fame.  And it's not an open issue. You argument that things being useless means they can't be true is just plain bizarre.yes, discrete metric spaces are trivial, boring, simple and maybe even "useless" because in discrete spaces all sets are open and closed, limit points don't exist, and only finite sets are compact.  Boring and useless.  But why would that make it false? And I'm not talking about discrete spaces anyway...

Comment: I'm not talking about *all* singletons being open.  If X= [0,1]U {2} then {2} is an open set.  But {1} is not.  Not all sets are open and closed.  So continuous means the reals.  Does "and beyond" $R^n $?  Where in the OP does it state the the metric space is the reals "and beyond".

Comment: Rudin' book may not cover the discrete space. So are other books. I explain to you many times, this is a last time. A good theory should be consistent on as many as cases as possible. If interior point being open set causes so many differences between continuous and discrete space, why do we have to use it? Why not just add non-empty condition to make it much consistent between continuous and discrete space? This is a common sense. Good mathematics always cover as many things as possible and keep consistency at the same time. This is an open issue I am sure.

Comment: Interior point being open for isolated metric points doesn't cause *any* conflicts or confusion and is utterly consistent.  It is simply a specific condition.  It's your bizarre idea to recreate an entirely different branch of mathematics and new definitions that is inconsistent.  If X = the real numbers then isolated points can not be interior points.  But that isn't because less famous but smarter mathematicians than Rudin had a committee and decided open and closed sets didn't make sense and needed to be impossible.  It's because math *is* consistent.

Comment: If X = the reals then the reals are dense and have the archimedian principle so every open ball is uncountable.  Hence isolated points can never be open sets.  That's utterly consistent with standard definitions.  Good math doesn't just make up entirely different rules and definitions because they want comfortable results.  Your math makes no sense and isn't used by anyone.  All three of discrete space, R with euclidean metric, and my case of X = [0,1]U {2} all use the same rules and definitions.  That something "doesn't make sense" or "doesn't have a purpose" is not how math works.

Comment: Which leads us back to my very first comment. int A U A' is not necessarily the same thing as A'. It is if X is the euclidean real metric, but it isn't if X is a discrete space or a non discrete space with isolated points. Instead you twist yourself in knots insisting mathematicians make up rules as they go along, that math is entirely different when we don't like the results, that topology is different if we don't like what another person on the internet says, that all books that disagree with you no matter the repute are "not right". You simply are not a consistent mathematician.

Answer (score -1):

That will be all the interior points and the limit points.  If the set has isolated points they will not be in the union.  That union will be the closure minus the isolated points of A.

Comment: isolated points are in the closure too

Comment: Did I say the isolated points weren't in the closure? Learn to read.  Of course, isolated points are in the closure.  That's why I had to specify they needed to be removed.  An isolated point is usually not an interior point (although it could be) and an isolated point is never a limit point.  So the interior points union the limit points will not include any non-interior isolated points.  $\int A \cup A'$ is NOT the closure.because it will not contain non int isolated points (if any)

Comment: fleablood, can you tell me any example of isolated interior point?

Comment: If you use the trivial discrete topology d (x,y)=1 if x $\ne $ y, then all sets are open and all points are isolated points.  But that's the discrete metric.  If your topological space X has isolated points in it, example the natural numbers or a union of intervals with a few isolated points.  Then the isolated points of the space are interior points of every set they are in.  However, if your space is the reals with the normal euclidean metric an isolated interior point is impossible...

Comment: For a point to be isolated point of A there must be a neighborhood with no other points in A.  To be an interior point there must be a neighborhood with every point in A.  If there is a neighborhood with *no* other points *at all* then it is both.  But x can only be both if there is a neighborhood with *only* x in it.  This can only happen if the *space* has a point that has *no* points near it.  If the space is dense (or what Hermes incorrectly calls continuous) this is impossible.  But there are cases where this happens.

Comment: So an example: let X={1/n} U {0}.  Let A = {1/2n}.  Then A is both open but not closed.  The limit point is 0 which is not in A.  The points 1/2n are both interior and isolated points.  For e < 1/2n - 1/(2n+1) the open ball with radius e around 1/2n contains *only* the point 1/2n.  So it is isolated because it contains no other point but 1/2n.  But it is also interior because the open ball is a subset of A.  This is possible only because all the points except 0 are discrete.